# If you upload a file to PHP that exceeds upload_max_filesize, does the upload terminate?

Tags: php, file-upload

As in title.

I have a upload_max_filesize limit of 2meg, if I upload a 3meg file will it stop uploading after 2megs or carry on until the full 3megs have been uploaded before deciding it's too big?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will it stop uploading after 2megs or carry on until the full 3megs have been uploaded before deciding it's too big?

The full 3 megs will be uploaded. The request is only then passed on to PHP, which will decide that it's too big.

The `error` flag will be populated as pointed out by @Steve.

IIRC, it's different if you hit *Apache's* [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) size: The request will be terminated immediately upon hitting the limit and an error page displayed.

Comment: @jammy you're welcome - although this isn't really PHP's fault, it simply has no chance to run before the request is completed and received by the web server. If you need reliable size checking, look into Flash-based uploading and/or the HTML 5 file upload API that I think can do a size check as well

Comment: thanks again - actually I'm looking at swfUploader currently, this question arose due to having a form that uploads 5 2mb images at the same time, and me testing with bigger images (up to 5meg). swfUploader appears to do everything i need it to do, client side - http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Comment: @jammy yup, SWFUpload is a fine product.

Answer (score -2):

It won't even begin.  It'll populate the $_FILES['filename']['error'] with the UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE constant.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "It won't even begin" isn't true. The upload process will run through until PHP can check the uploaded file's size. Everything else is correct

Comment: Yes, even Yahoo mail cannot stop us from start uploading a 4Gb file in file attachment section.

Comment: Wow.. live and learn.  I remember it exiting pretty early on in my tests.  Thanks for the correction :)